# Neo4j - Generate relationship between all nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have generated an unknown amount of nodes with the same label. Then I would like each node to be in relationship with all the others...

I tried the following CYPHER :

```
MATCH (n:Nodelabel),(m:Nodelabel)
MERGE (n)-[:EXCHANGE {cost: rand()*100}]->(m)
```

It's almost perfect but I get looping relationships : each node is in relationship with himself. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following CYPHER :

```
WHERE NOT n=m
```

So the full CYPHER answer is :

```
MATCH (n:Nodelabel),(m:Nodelabel)
WHERE NOT n=m
MERGE (n)-[:EXCHANGE {cost: rand()*100}]->(m)
```

Comment: Good answer, though you may want to make use of the inequality operator: `WHERE n <> m`